# convert update field second to time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 fields name FROM and TO. Both fields will have time in second (for example FROM=20520 and TO=39360). I would like to convert and update these fields to time format (for example FROM=20520 becomes FROM=05:420:00:00 and TO=39360 becomes TO=10:56:00:00)
Thank you.

Comment: What database system are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc.?

Comment: If you are already on 2008, why don't you use the [`time` datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) instead of `int`? Is the desired result a `time` or a `varchar`?

Comment: someone set in seconds. Now they want them convert to time not in seconds. I really need a query to convert and update these fields.

Comment: anyone can help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how you convert integers to time, you could work around this to update your values. @T is your current value.

```
declare @T int
set @T = 205020

select dateadd(hour, (@T / 1000000) % 100,
   dateadd(minute, (@T / 10000) % 100,
   dateadd(second, (@T / 100) % 100,
   dateadd(millisecond, (@T % 100) * 10, cast('00:00:00' as time(2))))))
```

**Edit**

you only need the seconds part.

```
 declare @T int
 set @T = 205020


 select dateadd(second, (@T / 100) % 100,cast('00:00:00' as time(2)))
```

**2nd Edit for bulks**

```
update Yourtable
set FromTime = dateadd(second, ([FROM] / 100) % 100,cast('00:00:00' as time(2))),
ToTime = dateadd(second, ([TO] / 100) % 100,cast('00:00:00' as time(2)))
where {YourFilter for you 10000 records}
```

Comment: I can use this, but the problem how to convert and update over 10000 records, not a single record

Comment: anyone can help me on this issue?